# Selecting rows between two dates

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(retail_sales_final.khadi_loan) as khadi_loan,
               customer_master.customer_name 
        FROM  retail_sales_final INNER JOIN customer_master 
        ON (retail_sales_final.customer_id =customer_master.customer_id) 
        WHERE khadi_loan > '0' 
        GROUP BY retail_sales_final.customer_id";
```

This is my query here i want to select it also with date's(between two dates) from both the tables
help me

Comment: What are the datatypes of date and provide tables info please.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a date column somewhere in your table, then you can simply set up your query like so:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM things
WHERE date BETWEEN date_A AND date_B
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(retail_sales_final.khadi_loan) as khadi_loan, customer_master.customer_name 
FROM  retail_sales_final 
INNER JOIN customer_master 
ON (retail_sales_final.customer_id =customer_master.customer_id) 
WHERE khadi_loan > '0' 
GROUP BY retail_sales_final.customer_id
HAVING date between X and Y;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll have to do this in SQL...

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName 
WHERE (Date1>='date1' AND Date2<='date2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(retail_sales_final.khadi_loan) as khadi_loan,
               customer_master.customer_name 
FROM  retail_sales_final INNER JOIN customer_master 
ON (retail_sales_final.customer_id =customer_master.customer_id) 
WHERE khadi_loan > '0' and date_column between first_date and second_date
GROUP BY retail_sales_final.customer_id
```